# getTextBeforeCursor/getSelectedText/getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

I am having a trouble with flutter. Yesterday before sleeping, my code worked fine, it added data on firebase too. Then i slept and now my program is not working. it keeps telling these error

```
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 6414): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 6414): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 6414): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
```

My app basic display 2 TextField where users enter pet's name and age. This error happens when i enter the pet name, then tap on textfield of pet age and the error is prints. I think there is an error when changing between 2 textfield. However, yesterday my app worked fine!

I copied and modified the code from [this link](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-use-firebase-queries-in-flutter-361f21005467) to learn how the app create, update data on firebase.

Here is [tkshnwesper solution](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11321). However when i follow tkshnwesper, my program still shows same error.

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Pets',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Register Pet'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("Please Register Your Pet ",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                          fontSize: 30,
                          fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                          fontStyle: FontStyle.italic)),
                  RegisterPet(),
                ]),
          )),
    );
  }
}

class RegisterPet extends StatefulWidget {
  RegisterPet({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RegisterPetState createState() => _RegisterPetState();
}

class _RegisterPetState extends State<RegisterPet> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final nameController = TextEditingController();
  final ageController = TextEditingController();
  final dbRef = Firestore.instance.collection("pets");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: TextFormField(
                  controller: nameController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Enter Pet Name",
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  // The validator receives the text that the user has entered.
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Enter Pet Name';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: TextFormField(
                  controller: ageController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Enter Pet Age",
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  // The validator receives the text that the user has entered.
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Please Pet Age';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      RaisedButton(
                        color: Colors.lightBlue,
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                            print("aaaaaaa");
                            dbRef.add({
                              "name": nameController.text,
                              "age": ageController.text,
                            }).then((_) {
                              Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                                  SnackBar(content: Text('Successfully Added')));
                            }).catchError((onError) {
                              Scaffold.of(context)
                                  .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(onError)));
                            });
                            print("aaaoooa");
                          };
                          ageController.text = '';
                          nameController.text = '';
                        },
                        child: Text('Submit'),
                      ),
                      RaisedButton(
                        color: Colors.amber,
                        onPressed: () {
//                          Navigator.push(
//                            context,
//                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()),
//                          );
                        },
                        child: Text('Navigate'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )),
            ])));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    ageController.dispose();
    nameController.dispose();
  }
}
```

Also, can you guys help me how to display firebase data of "pets" collection as a list on the emulator?

Answer (score 0):

getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection is a warning

fetching collection documents:

```
FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  future: Firestore.instance.collection('pets').getDocuments(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot){
    switch(snapshot.connectionState){
      case ConnectionState.waiting:
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
        break;
      default :
        List <DocumentSnapshot> documents = snapshot.data.documents;
        return ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
          itemCount: documents.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
            /// define how you want to show your each documents data...
            return ListTile();
          }
        );
    }
  }
);
```

if you can error on getting collection, feel free to comment, otherwise accept and upvote!!!!

Comment: Thank you for help, i still struggle with getting collection but i upvoted for you. Can you help me how to only display a length of character about 20 - 30 character in list view? For example i have a data string call 'description' on firebase and it is very long like `This is a very long description` should be displayed like `This is a very...`. Thank you in advance!

Comment: what's the problem in getting collection?